# Internet explorer CSS FIX. Having trouble with floats in internet explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float

I have a simple problem but have not figured out what might be solution just yet. I used a css reset to fix the issue with internet explorer, but no dice. I also do not want to use relative - absolute positioning. If you go to http://securitycamerasflorida.net via firefox, chrome, or safari it looks the way I wanted which content and sidebar is next to each other. They are both positioned with float but if you click on one of the cities you can see in IE that sidebar is pushed at the bottom of the page.

Comment: What's with the wacky URL?  Are you worried about spam bots finding your public web site or are you trying to hide it from this sites filters?

Comment: Actually non of the above. I just don't want the site's issues visible to people when its googled.

Comment: I realized that it also works on IE8 but not in IE7. Also it is not tested on IE6

Comment: @hightouch - but you do realize that people with sufficient reputation can edit your post any time and change that URL...

Comment: @hightech - and these kind of "problems" are common an are no security threat for your site. So I don't really see a need for this obscurity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help you: [About Conditional Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Just tried it also. Please see http://www.securitycamerasflorida.net/cctv-miami.php ie css has a float right property for some reason it is not taking affect

Comment: got it now just had to put the conditional after the original statement thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a right margin on your `<div id="content">` and remove the left margin from your `<div id="sidebar">`

You can a wacky double margin in IE6 when you put a margin in the same direction you're floating.